# Script to find the the number of rows those were update in the last 1hr

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This script does give me the list of changed rows but I also need to make sure that the number of changed rows should be equal to the number of rows those were update in the last 1 hour which would give me more comfort level on validation.

Here is the code which gives me the list of changed rows. Except does give me all the rows from the first select statement which are not in the second select if I am not wrong. I am just wondering how to check the number of rows that were updated in the last hr which must match the count of rows when I run this below query.

```
  Select [Accounting_Period_ID]
  ,[Policy_Number]
  ,[Risk_ID]
  ,[Product_ID]
  ,[Inception_Date_ID]
  ,[Effective_Date_ID]
  ,[Expiration_Date_ID]
  ,[Cancellation_Date_ID]
  ,[Reinstate_Date_ID]
  ,[Policy_Source_System_ID]
  ,[Risk_Geo_ID]
  ,[Risk_Profile_ID]
  ,[Policy_Status_ID]
  ,[Agency_ID]
  ,[Limit_Selection_ID]
  ,[Written_Premium_MTD]
  ,[Written_Premium_ITD]
  ,[Fees_MTD]
  ,[Fees_ITD]
  ,[Commission_MTD]
  ,[Commission_ITD]
  ,[Earned_Premium_MTD]
  ,[Earned_Premium_ITD]
  ,[In_Force_Count]
  ,[New_Business_Count]
  ,[Renewed_Count]
  ,[Cancelled_Count]
  ,[Reinstated_Count]
  ,[Dwelling_Limit]
  ,[Other_Structures_Base_Limit]
  ,[Other_Structures_Extended_Limit]
  ,[Other_Structures_Total_Limit]
  ,[Contents_Limit]
  ,[Additional_Living_Expense_Limit]
  ,[Liability_Limit]
  ,[Medical_Limit]
  ,[Total_Insured_Value]
  ,[Replacement_Value]
  ,[AOP_Deductible]
  ,[Days_in_Force]
  ,[Earned_House_Years]
  ,[Cancellation_Entry_Date_ID]
  ,[Reinstate_Entry_Date_ID]
  ,[Seq]
  ,[Inserted_Date]
  ,[Inserted_By]
  ,[Last_Updated_Date]
  ,[Last_Updated_By]
  ,[Insurance_score]
  ,[Rewrite_Count]
  ,[Entry_Date_ID] from Datamart.Policy.Fact_Monthly_Policy_Snap_20190403 
where Policy_Source_System_ID = 8
EXCEPT
Select [Accounting_Period_ID]
  ,[Policy_Number]
  ,[Risk_ID]
  ,[Product_ID]
  ,[Inception_Date_ID]
  ,[Effective_Date_ID]
  ,[Expiration_Date_ID]
  ,[Cancellation_Date_ID]
  ,[Reinstate_Date_ID]
  ,[Policy_Source_System_ID]
  ,[Risk_Geo_ID]
  ,[Risk_Profile_ID]
  ,[Policy_Status_ID]
  ,[Agency_ID]
  ,[Limit_Selection_ID]
  ,[Written_Premium_MTD]
  ,[Written_Premium_ITD]
  ,[Fees_MTD]
  ,[Fees_ITD]
  ,[Commission_MTD]
  ,[Commission_ITD]
  ,[Earned_Premium_MTD]
  ,[Earned_Premium_ITD]
  ,[In_Force_Count]
  ,[New_Business_Count]
  ,[Renewed_Count]
  ,[Cancelled_Count]
  ,[Reinstated_Count]
  ,[Dwelling_Limit]
  ,[Other_Structures_Base_Limit]
  ,[Other_Structures_Extended_Limit]
  ,[Other_Structures_Total_Limit]
  ,[Contents_Limit]
  ,[Additional_Living_Expense_Limit]
  ,[Liability_Limit]
  ,[Medical_Limit]
  ,[Total_Insured_Value]
  ,[Replacement_Value]
  ,[AOP_Deductible]
  ,[Days_in_Force]
  ,[Earned_House_Years]
  ,[Cancellation_Entry_Date_ID]
  ,[Reinstate_Entry_Date_ID]
  ,[Seq]
  ,[Inserted_Date]
  ,[Inserted_By]
  ,[Last_Updated_Date]
  ,[Last_Updated_By]
  ,[Insurance_score]
  ,ISNULL([Rewrite_Count],0) Rew
  ,[Entry_Date_ID] from Datamart.Policy.Fact_Monthly_Policy_Snap
   where Policy_Source_System_ID = 8
```

Comment: How in the world could anybody on these forums know this?

Comment: Are you tracking a recorddate of some sort anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

DATEADD(hh,-1,GETDATE()) gives you the actual Time minus 1 hour .this you can compare with Last_Updated_Date.
Count(*) gives you the number of rows.

Comment: Thank you! Let me try this.